# PC with HDD and SSD: Delete information in the HDD

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, delete

In the HDD of my computer I have a partition with windows and ubuntu. I recently decided to upgrade my computer by installing an SSD. On the SSD I installed Ubuntu, however, I forgot to erase all the information I had on my HDD (including the two operating systems I mentioned above). I would like to use the HDD to only store information, but I don't know what procedure to follow from the ubuntu that I have in the SSD.

Thank you for the support.

Comment: Do you want to keep Windows (and does it boot)? If so just format the other partition. If not probably better to delete everything and create a new partition. All of this should be obvious even for beginners. What exactly are you stuck with? Please always [edit] the question if need to add a clarification or additional information.

Comment: I just have edited the question, thanks for the suggestion. I hope my question is understood this time

Comment: You can use Disks. Simply select the drive in the left panel. Then select each partition and use the "-" button to remove (you may need to unmount it first, use the square button). Once clean, all unallocated space, you can use "+" to create a new partition, choose EXT4, done.

Comment: @ChanganAuto, thanks. It works!